# Hive table replace timestamp column NULL value with Custom default

Tags: hive, hadoop2

I understand how to keep default value as current timestamp, But I have requirement to replace NULL value in timestamp column with custom date/timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

There is `coalesce` function that you can use, e.g.,

```
select coalesce(column_name, cast("2020-07-28 12:34:56" as timestamp))
```